# How to find host of an unidentified VM in a network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, bridge

For example someone have installed server with a DHCP on VM connected to a corporate network breaking its operation, so I have IP of that VM, but how to find out IP of its host system ?

Comment: one addition: there is no hypervisor or any kind of vm managment system in this case, vm is installed on some unidentifiend user workstation in a network (VirtualBox, VMware Workstation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've provided almost no information here making it a terribly-worded question but I'd suggest that you can find the host (you don't even mention a hypervisor!) via inspecting your switch CAM tables. If you can find the physical switch port carrying the VM's traffic then you should be able to find the host's ports too.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it won't be easy.
If your switches have management interface, try checking where given MAC address is connected to and you will find owner of this DHCP server. Yes - it takes some time and effort to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky - basically yo ufind the MAC address o the sender, then you identify the owner of the MAC address in your VM management system. Obviously you HAVE one, otherwise you must replace that with some poor guy checking every server manually.

Then you go on and fire the incompetent admin - DHCP guarding is something a modern network shoulddo on multiple levels. In my small company that is done by both, the Hyper-V servers (DHCP guard is a new feature in 2012) as well as the switches that only allow DHCP packets from specific ports.